# Overmoderation problem on SO

Tags: discussion, moderation

Lately I've seen an unusual number of SO questions being downvoted and closed, even though they're legitimate questions.  Granted, most are easily answered, duplicates, etc., but it communicates a message of "Hey, that's a stupid question; you're not welcome here" to new users.  I really feel it's hurting the community.

In game mechanics, this is a reinforcing loop.  People are rewarded with badges for moderating, whether or not it was good moderation.  We're punishing real questions, and rewarding fake moderation.

Has anyone else seen this problem, and what's a good way of fixing it?

**Edit:**

I've been on SO for three years.  I understand why questions are closed.  I also understand legitimate reasons to downvote.  I'm talking about a recent inundation with petty punishment for questions that are easy or already asked.

I will add examples as I come across them again.  However, I was really hoping for a legitimate discussion on this issue.

**Two Recent Examples:**

[why should I convert my 32 bit application to 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918812/why-should-i-convert-my-32-bit-application-to-64-bit/16918842#16918842)

[addClass to an element with that class already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864542/addclass-to-an-element-with-that-class-already#comment24325776_16864542)

Comment: Your question would have more validity if you included examples.

Comment: You guys are proving my point.  Still need an example?

Comment: Yes, because http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @landons Yes, we do.  Your question is being downvoted (in part) because you're not supporting your points with hard evidence.  The question is not well researched, it is not concrete in what types of questions you're referring two, or to the extent of the problem.  That makes it low quality, and as such downvotes are appropriate.

Comment: P.s. if they are duplicates, what's the problem with closure?

Comment: @landons Preferably more than one.

Comment: You miss the point of Stack Overflow. It's NOT for everyone. It's NOT meant for "solve this for me" aka "give me the codez" questions.

Comment: You can close a duplicate without downvoting.  I think it's petty to punish people because you don't like their question.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was different here.  Conditioned to be offended ;)

Comment: @landons A duplicate closure doesn't mean we don't like the question. It just means it's already been asked.

Comment: @landons, what makes you think it's because we "don't like" their questions, instead of the questions showing no research effort or not being useful?

Comment: @landons The downvote tooltip reads "This question does not show any research effort". For the vast majority of duplicates this is indeed the case. That said, examples would make your point here stronger than it is now, if you have one.

Comment: With or without examples, does no one feel the same?  It seriously feels like a community of vulchers now. It used to feel helpful.

Comment: We don't have so much a problem of over moderation as one of too many low quality, unresearched questions.

Comment: @landons, *vulchers*? As in "one who makes lame kills in an online game, usually when the opponent is low on health or fighting another player"? Are you sure that analogy stands?

Comment: That's not specifically the reference I was using, but yes.  People with low rep seem to be assumed to be idiots, and are rarely given the benefit of the doubt.  This discourages them from ever assimilating into the community

Comment: Vultures, I assume @landons? And be careful not to extrapolate your negative experiences with a few users to the community as a whole.

Comment: Oops.  Yes, vulture ;)

Comment: And I haven't been treated with disrespect, only noticed it with a few recent noobies

Comment: Trolls.  Trolls was the word I was looking for.

Comment: The last thing we should be concerned about is new users' feelings. *Everyone* is new around here. We have standards and we should ruthlessly enforce them. Close and downvote. **Mercilessly.**

Answer (score 7):

> In game mechanics, this is a reinforcing loop. People are rewarded with badges for moderating, whether or not it was good moderation. We're punishing real questions, and rewarding fake moderation.

The only badges given for moderation are those given for participating in the review queues (except those you get for flagging, which are already audited by diamond moderators).  Review audits were added a few months ago to try and cut down on robo-reviewers who game those badges, and I've seen a big improvement in the quality of reviews since that time.  I don't think we're rewarding fake moderation, and it's hard to tell if we're punishing real questions without some examples.  (For what it's worth, I think far more bad questions get through than good questions get blocked.)

Comment: I'll give you that.  But it's like the police.  Crime goes up, police crack down.  Then, there can be an abuse of power if you're not careful.  That's what I see happening.

Comment: @landons If there's any abuse of power going on, we're really going to need to see some examples.  We're happy to reopen questions that were either closed prematurely or improved after the fact.  What we *don't* want to do is cut newbies slack just because they're new. We need to close their low-quality questions so they read the FAQ and learn the standards, just like everyone else.

Comment: I completely agree.  I just feel we're a little trigger happy.  See those two examples (not great, but very recent, and help my communication slightly)

Comment: @landons Those are both borderline examples. The first one is kind of broad, like it's asking for a list of possible reasons, but it's also easily Google-able.  The second one is better, but it also seems like the OP could have easily just tried it to see what happens.

Comment: That's true it's easily Google-able, but it's also easy to be helpful, though some prefer to punish people to "preserve high quality" (at the detriment of the community).  Yes, the OP could have tried it, but he was specifically concerned about not knowing what he doesn't know.  It literally takes less time to say "Nope, you're good" than to punish someone for asking a borderline question.

Comment: @landons The point is that we don't want a bunch of questions where the answer is "Nope, you're good."  Those questions *should* be closed (or improved).  This isn't a case of over-moderation.

Comment: *"preserve high quality" (at the detriment of the community)* High quality is good for the community, period. If we become Yahoo Answers, all of the good answerers will leave and the site will be useless.

Answer (score 3):

SO, and even all SE sites, aren't here to answer all types of questions.  Heck, they're not even here to answer all *good* questions.  In order to ensure a very high quality standard of questions and answers the site has narrowed the scope of questions that can be answered.  Questions which may be well written, well researched, applicable to many people (even programmers, who are the target audience) are not necessarily appropriate for SO.

Different types of questions have been determined to be out of scope for different reasons.  For example, questions that are designed to encourage debate or extended discussion are not allowed because the Q/A format of the site just isn't well suited towards a back and forth; it really only works when there's one question and one answer.

Duplicate questions are (where possible) closed as duplicates rather than answered so that the information about that topic isn't spread out across lots of posts and is instead consolidated into one canonical question that can be of the highest quality.

Voting, both up and down, also plays a very important role in the site.  Providing feedback to users (for both questions and answers) is a rather effective way of indicating quality.  It helps readers know what answers they should trust, it helps answerers know what questions are worth their time, etc.  It also indicates to question askers whether they are providing high quality content or not; and if not, allowing them the opportunity of improving their post(s) so that they can get more and better answers.