# Guide new members with less than 100 rep when posting new questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users

There has been a lot of discussion in the past about ways to possibly "guide" new users. Some of these ideas consist of "[Welcome Tours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126009/create-a-guided-tour-for-new-users)," shoving the FAQ/Help section down their throats, etc. Just the improvements recently made to the new Help area is a good start.

However, we have to be realistic. Most new members come here because they just want quick information about their problem. They don't care about etiquette, rules, badges, or reputation. They aren't going to sit and read through pages of bullets on how to properly post a question. Therefore, why don't we help these users learn about posting questions properly right where they're going: the question submission form.

I'd recommend that any new user with under 100 reputation get subjected to some of the following ideas.

When they click "Post Your Question", we do some looking into some common oversights of new questions. These could all be dismissable prompts that would allow the poster to go back and revise before posting or just continue on, ignorant of their faults.

For example:

- Look for use of the Code Sample markdown. If it doesn't exist, we display a message along the lines of "A good question typically has *source code* in it, showing problematic areas in your code or things you have tried. Would you like to add some code?"
- Look for common sins, such as "Hi", "Hello", "Thanks", "Thanks in advance". Don't prevent them from posting, but again display a message along the lines of "Good questions only contain relevant information to your problem. There's no need to introduce yourself or say 'thank you' in your post."
- Others?

Again, if the poster decides to ignore and post, then this doesn't get around the problem of low-quality first posts. However, making the poster acknowledge the fact that something may be improved about their question before posting it may lighten the load of low-quality first posts.

Comment: To the source code bit, also include something that indicates they should check to see if they missed marking something as source code, that happens a lot of course :)

Comment: Some of what you say I agree with, some I don't. I do think there should be a prompt saying "please include any source code if applicable"...

Comment: @Joe can you suggest an algorithm/RegEx/whatever that would identify code not properly formatted as code? Note that to be useful it would have to magically identify code written in any programming language, query dialect, etc.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting automatically doing so, but rather as this was a suggestion to remind the user to post code, include a subnote of "On the other hand, if you did include code and didn't properly highlight it, please do so".  :)  But your magical code regex would be wonderful, too...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Clippy is not the answer. There is plenty of material already available that they can read; we don't need to go to great lengths to add additional programmatic nagging like, "would you like to add some source code?" I would bet that most of the time, if someone didn't already think that source code would be a good thing to include in their question, that additional nag isn't going to make them that much more likely to realize it.

[image]

The salutations and grammar stuff don't really make questions bad or take away from the thrust of the question; besides, they're cleaned up pretty quickly by a legion of selfless editor lemmings anyway.

If you see a bad question, you can always ask them, "have you been to [the new help center](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter)?" Trying to automate this, IMHO, is going to be far less effective than real human interaction, and it will be difficult to technically implement on top of that. For example, someone here mentioned the fact that not all questions need to have code to be questions, which is quite true. The code might also be there, but formatted as a quote, `inline` or not formatted. Telling them to include code when they have but just didn't format it correctly is going to be pretty annoying.

Please review [this recent meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183195/strict-moderation-on-stack-overflow) and of course all of the duplicates it points to - this issue has been discussed ad nauseum.

Comment: B-B-B-But what about [Clippycorn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127701/how-can-i-get-the-2012-april-fools-joke-to-appear/127704#127704)? :(

Comment: That's a fantastic Clippy.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to answer a question. Want some help with that?

Answer (score 5):

A lot of this we already do in filtering out poor quality questions.  But for users who are struggling with these concepts, spoonfeeding them how to improve is the **wrong** thing to do.  It's not *terribly* hard to write a cogent question on SO, and if someone fails to do this, then chances are the problem is not enough thought on the part of the OP, not lack of instruction on the part of our UI.

Answer (score 1):

I think bombarding new users with a large number of things may end up causing more problems. For example, if you say

```
a good question typically has code
```

what happens when they ask something that doesn't require any? They may try to force some in in an attempt to make a "good question". These are probably the people who don't bother to read the FAQ so I think if anything, it should only have one pop up (assuming the info isn't already in their face) that says something akin to

```
When posting your question, be sure to include your source code 
(if applicable), what steps you've taken to try and answer your own question,
and why they didn't work for you. Questions that provide this information 
typically are answered much faster, while leaving this information out may lead
people to ignore your question in favor of better formatted one.
```

I would suggest better wording but the hope would be to encourage those who are too impatient to read the FAQ to understand. I feel the fear of having their question ignored may help convince them to put in a bare minimum of effort.